# How to prevent multiple login from single user name

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiple-login

How to prevent multiple login from single user name? I am saving username and password in database. I want the user to login from 1 place at a time only.

For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433

Below is a code which I have tried

Config File

```
<configuration>                             
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpModules>
            <add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" >
            <add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Class File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Demo1
{
    public class SingleSessionEnforcement : IHttpModule
    {
        public SingleSessionEnforcement()
        {
            // No construction needed
        }

        private void OnPostAuthenticate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid sessionToken;

            HttpApplication httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext httpContext = httpApplication.Context;

            // Check user's session token
            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket =
                                            ((FormsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity).Ticket;

                if (authenticationTicket.UserData != "")
                {
                    sessionToken = new Guid(authenticationTicket.UserData);
                }
                else
                {
                    // No authentication ticket found so logout this user
                    // Should never hit this code
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                    return;
                }

                MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(authenticationTicket.Name);

                // May want to add a conditional here so we only check
                // if the user needs to be checked. For instance, your business
                // rules for the application may state that users in the Admin
                // role are allowed to have multiple sessions
                Guid storedToken = new Guid(currentUser.Comment);

                if (sessionToken != storedToken)
                {
                    // Stored session does not match one in authentication
                    // ticket so logout the user
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Nothing to dispose
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(OnPostAuthenticate);
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Demo1
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TextBox userNameTextBox = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("UserName");
            SingleSessionPreparation.CreateAndStoreSessionToken(userNameTextBox.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo1.login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <asp:TextBox ID="userNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
            Password:    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is giving this error:

> Could not load type 'SingleSessionEnforcement'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'SingleSessionEnforcement'.

Please refere the attached image of the error:

[image: Error image]

Please guide me to solve the issue.

Comment: CSS would be better than a bunch of `&nbsp;` for page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type attribute needs to include the namespace:

```
<add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="Demo1.SingleSessionEnforcement" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope by this time you could have got the solution. If not, please see my comments below:

The problem is in web.config file. Httpmodule can initiate only once in config file.

If IIS 7.0 or below, use the following one in system.web,
`<httpModules>
 <add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
</httpModules>`

If it is > IIS 7.0, use the following one in system.webServer,
`<modules>
<add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
</modules>`

Comment: Hello Siva, welcome to SO! Shouldn't the namespace be included in the type attribute as suggested by Richard in his answer ?